# Stocktwits api public streams/symbol stops working

Tags: stocktwits

I tried [this](https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/AAPL.json).

Get response

```
{"response":{"status":429},"errors":[{"message":"Rate limit exceeded. Client may not make more than 200 requests an hour."}]}
```

I only tried several times during different hours. But always get the above message.

Comment: I suspect the API is down. It is also happening to me. My app is in development and does not approach anywhere near 200 request per hour.

Answer (score 1):

The streams/symbol endpoint requires Partner-Level Access now.

The API documentation page has been updated recently.  This was one of the things added:

> This API end-point is only available through Partner-Level Access